Reading PITR (Point-In-Time-Recovery) data via Google App Engine gives KeyError for read_time
I am getting a KeyError when I try to use PITR to read entities from a couple of days ago, using NDB (I have confirmed that PITR has been enabled for this DB, and that this date is within the 7-day window).
Error (updated to include more log file as requested):
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 390, in __new__
    config_option = obj._options[key]
KeyError: 'read_time'"

"Exception on /admin/fix [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 390, in __new__
    config_option = obj._options[key]
KeyError: 'read_time'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 36, in __call__
    return self.view(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1138, in add_context_wrapper
    return synctaskletfunc(*args, **kwds)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1117, in synctasklet_wrapper
    return taskletfunc(*args, **kwds).get_result()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1087, in tasklet_wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/srv/admin/fix.py", line 803, in fix_handler
    assets = ee_item.Asset.query(ee_item.Asset.estate_id==6359851389157376).fetch(100,read_time=want_time)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 182, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1266, in fetch
    return self.fetch_async(limit, **q_options).get_result()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 182, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1285, in fetch_async
    options = self._make_options(q_options)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1468, in _make_options
    options = QueryOptions(**q_options)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 392, in __new__
    raise TypeError('Unknown configuration option (%s)' % err)
TypeError: Unknown configuration option ('read_time')"
timestamp: "2024-09-17T13:44:07.645924Z"

Calling code uses ndb (works fine without the read_time argument):
want_time = datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 13, 4, 30, 5)
entities = MyClass.query(Myclass.my_propname==123).fetch(read_time=want_time)

Not sure if it's relevant, but I am using legacy bundled services, so in my app.yaml, I am setting:
runtime: python39
app_engine_apis: true


Please share the error logs of this issue.

@SupriyaBharti, I have now included more of the log file lines, at your request.  Let me know if there's something else you were seeking, and how to include it.
